# How to use route name in laravel from api route

Tags: laravel

I've been using ajax to access the google api, the route I've been using is from the API route in laravel. The problem is that I cant use the route name in the ajax because when using the api route there is a prefix 'api'.

Comment: you need to add the example of code you're using to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can able to access the route name directly inside ajax as a URL.

API Route with `name` method:

```
Route::get('/user/profile', [UserProfileController::class, 'show'])->name('profile');
```

Where `profile` is your route name. Inside ajax call in the laravel blade file.

```
url:"{{ route('profile') }}",
```

Comment: Thank you it is working now. How can I send a js variable to the route, because my api route receives a second parameter